# ReactJS: how to get selections/state from a dropdown that is a child component?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, drop-down-menu

I am trying to develop an application that allows you to create multiple drop downs. Based on the selection of the drop down, some context specific checklists are shown. At the bottom of the page I want to have (((one))) button to submit all of the checked items and the `selectedValue` from the drop down to a web service.

The problem is, I don't know how I would lift the state of the `selectedValue` to the parent component that houses all of the drop downs and the submit button.

This is the `render()` method from my top level component, which I think might give you an idea of what I want the page to look like if this is still unclear:

```
render(){
 let dropDownValues = this.state.dropDownValues;
 let dropDowns = [];
 for (let i=0; i<this.state.counter;i++){
    dropDowns.push(<DropDown key={i} values={dropDownValues} />
 }

 return(
     <div>
        {dropDowns}
        <button onClick={()=>this.addDropDown()}>+</button>
        <button onClick={()=>this.removeDropDown()}>-</button>
        <form method="post" onsubmit={this.postToWebservice(allTheStuffFromTheDropDownsContext)}>
       <input type="submit" value="Submit Request To WebService"
        </form>
     </div>
 );
}
```

Comment: You can try adding an onChange event handler to your <select> instances. Pass it a function callback to update `state` with the current value of `selectedIndex`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the Immutable.js library's 'Map'  to handle the underlying issue that I was having: identifying which dropDown was which via the callback.

At first I tried several things by passing an id along with the callback but (due to my lack of understanding javascript) I was getting the desired effect although the console was throwing "cannot find property bind of undefined" when I tried to pass a second variable to the callback e.g. callBack={(evt,id)=>this.callBack(evt,id).bind(this)}

Anyways, I created a Map in the App's state and updated it via the callback that was passed to the DropDowns:

```
    import {Map as iMap} from 'immutable';
     Foo extends Container {

           constructor(){
              super();
              this.state = {
               ......,
               dropDownMenuMap: iMap();
           }

           clickCallBack(selected, checked, key){
               let dropDownMenuMap = this.state.DropDownMenuMap.set(key, {dropDownSelection: selected, checkedItems: checked});
               this.setState({dropDownMenuMap: dropDownMenuMap});
            }

            render(){
              let dropDowns = []
              for(let i=0;i<this.state.counter;i++){
               dropDowns.push(<DropDown id={i} callback={this.clickCallBack.bind(this)}/>);
              }
              return(....);
            }

}
```

and passed the callback to the dropDownMenus with an id (simply the value of i in the for loop) to keep track of which dropDownMenu was making the callback to use as the key in the Map.

Answer (score 1):

Pass a callback to your `DropDown` component. So if item checked, the callback will be called and your top level component can handle this.

```
dropDownSelected(selected) {
  this.state.selectedValue = ...
}
render(){
 let dropDownValues = this.state.dropDownValues;
 let dropDowns = [];
 for (let i=0; i<this.state.counter;i++){
    dropDowns.push(<DropDown key={i} values={dropDownValues} onDropDownSelected={this.dropDownSelected.bind(this)} />
 }

 return(
     <div>
        {dropDowns}
        <button onClick={()=>this.addDropDown()}>+</button>
        <button onClick={()=>this.removeDropDown()}>-</button>
        <form method="post" onsubmit={this.postToWebservice(allTheStuffFromTheDropDownsContext)}>
       <input type="submit" value="Submit Request To WebService"
        </form>
     </div>
 );
}
```